# Gatsby multi language & DatoCMS

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, multilingual

I'm making a bilingual website on **Gatsby**.
Content, in my case blogs come from **Datocms**.
How to implement it.
I don't want to make a separate page for each language.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

DatoCMS has [very good docs](https://www.datocms.com/docs/general-concepts/localization) about i18n, and for Gatsby specific pages I recommend [gatsby-plugin-react-i18next](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-react-i18next/). There are a few examples out there